# Pass Command to Page from AppShell.xaml page Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using the tabbed xamarin forms with the following code in my AppShell.xaml:

```
 <TabBar Route="tabbar">
        <ShellContent Title="Top Rated" Icon="icon_top.png" Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Recent" Icon="icon_recent.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:RecentPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Oldest" Icon="icon_old.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:OldestPage}" />
</TabBar>
```

Now I want to use the same view for both RecentPage and OldestPage but pass a parameter to the view to know what to display, in the code-behind you can do something like this:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(RecentPage)}?{nameof(RecentPage.Type)}={1}")
```

which would change the view based on that parameter.  Is there a way to do it for the tabbar?

So Ideally I want something like this:

```
 <TabBar Route="tabbar">
        <ShellContent Title="Top Rated" Icon="icon_top.png" Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Recent" Icon="icon_recent.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:PostsPage>Recent}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Oldest" Icon="icon_old.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:PostsPage>Oldest}" />
</TabBar>
```

Comment: "Now I want to use the same view" you are providing to ShellContent.ContentTemplate a Page not a View, do you mean the same Page?

Answer (score 0):

> which would change the view based on that parameter. Is there a way to do it for the tabbar?

I guess that you want to pass parameter to local shellcontent's constructor by xaml.

I suggest you can use [Bindable Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) to do. Create bindable property in ContentPage.

```
 public partial class Gallery : ContentPage
{
    public string Arg
    {
        set { SetValue(ArgProperty, value); }
        get { return (string)GetValue(ArgProperty); }
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty ArgProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Arg), typeof(string), typeof(Gallery), string.Empty,defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
                                                     propertyChanged: ArgPropertyChanged);

    private static void ArgPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (Gallery)bindable;
        control.label1.Text = newValue.ToString();
    }
    public Gallery()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                 
    }
}
```

I use Label to get parameter.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label
            x:Name="label1"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>

  <ShellContent
        Title="About"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}"
        Icon="tab_about.png"
        Route="AboutPage" />
    <ShellContent
        Title="Browse"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}"
        Icon="tab_feed.png" />
    <ShellContent Title="Browse" Icon="tab_feed.png">
        <local:Gallery Arg="name" />
    </ShellContent>
```

**Update:**

I suggest you can use [Xamarin.Forms MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to pass data to viewmodel.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label
            x:Name="label1"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

        <Label Text="{Binding str}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>

 public partial class Gallery : ContentPage
{
    public string str;
    public string Arg
    {
        set { SetValue(ArgProperty, value); }
        get { return (string)GetValue(ArgProperty); }
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty ArgProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Arg), typeof(string), typeof(Gallery), string.Empty,defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
                                                     propertyChanged: ArgPropertyChanged);

    private static void ArgPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (Gallery)bindable;
        control.label1.Text = newValue.ToString();
        MessagingCenter.Send<string, string>("test", "Hi", newValue.ToString());

    }

  
    public Gallery()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new viewmodel();         
    }
}
public class viewmodel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _str;
    public string str
    {
        get { return _str; }
        set
        {
            _str = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("str");
        }
    }
    public viewmodel()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string, string>("test", "Hi", (sender, arg) =>
        {
            str = arg;
        });
    }
   
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, that looks like what I need, my problem is that everything is on a ViewModel, so my page where InitializeComponent code is, I have the following:     BindingContext = _viewModel = new PostsViewModel();  How do I pass the value to the ViewModel?

Comment: @LearningEveryDay2.0 Please see my update.